# Displaying most recent items on subsite lists on parent site

Tags: list, workflow, web-part, list-view, flow

I am currently creating a PMO site / Project Overview Site.

I have my main site functioning as a portfolio which gives a view of data from all subsites under it (these sub sites will be the various projects we are working on).

On each of the project sub sites (created using the same template) there is a List created for a Project status report.

I want to be able to display the latest entry in these lists for all sub sites, and display them all in one view/list on the parent site (main portfolio page).

What is the best way to do this - Workflow / Flow / Content rollup?

Thanks
S

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? And standard of Enterprise?

Comment: Sharepoint Online (Modern Sites) / Enterprise

Comment: I would say use search. But there is no out of the box content by search webpart for modern pages. What we have done is create a custom aspx page with a rest call to the search api. And iFrame it. You could create a spfx webpart to do the same or look if there is already a community spfx webpart

Comment: The "Highlighted Content" web part can be used in Modern, and that is based on Search.  It's not very flexible though, so I don't think it would help in this scenario - i.e. I can't think of a way to only show 1 most recent item from every sub-site.  I wonder if PowerBI would be more suitable?